# In Android, where are files saved by default?

Tags: android

If I save a file without any path name .. e.g. "abc.txt" ... where would it be saved on the device ?

where should I look in emulator file system if to try to find a file I saved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I save a file without any path name .. e.g. "abc.txt" ... where would it be saved on the device ?

Don't do that.

Use `getFilesDir()` to get at the root of your application-local file area on internal storage. Or, use `openFileOutput()`, which gives you an `OutputStream` to a file in the directory identified by `getFilesDir()`.

Answer (score 7):

`/data/data/your.app.package.name/files`, but note this can be device dependent so you should follow CommonsGuy's advice!